# Heroku PostgresSQL: How to replay statement logs to another server

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We're using Heroku Postgres v12 for production web app and plan to upgrade to v13. I want to be able to replay statements from previous days log to

1. warm cache on upgraded instance (Heroku will switch it's hardware)
2. simulate production load on testing environments

I tried [pgreplay](https://github.com/laurenz/pgreplay) and [pgreplay-go](https://github.com/gocardless/pgreplay-go/), but both require me to set custom `log_line_prefix` which I can't do on Heroku Postgres.

What other options am I missing?

Given my tasks and the nature of the web app, we can drop any data\schema modification queries and only replay `SELECT`s, I also don't care much about the order.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but with AWS RDS DB, unable to find a ready solution.

Because changing `log_line_prefix` on RDS is not supported, I wrote a dead simple log converter from RDS `csvlog` to `pgreplay-go`, works for `SELECT` only load

https://gist.github.com/mvasilenko/6d6b01782d0d08ea72218327835016e0